# Rails form select truncate value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I have a rails form using a select tag as follows:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:question_id, Question.all, :id, :content) %>
```

My goal is to shorten the length of the content, in the dropdown list in the form. So, I added a method and changed my form to:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:question_id, Question.all, :id, :truncated_content) %>
```

In my question model I have:

```
def truncated_content
 self.content.truncate(140)
end
```

In my console, the result of question.truncated_content is 
=> nil

Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe there is nothing in the content field

Comment: you have to try this `Question.all.map{|q| [q.text.truncate(5),q.id] }` try this instead of `Question.all`

Comment: Not sure if truncate (https://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate) will return `nil` in any case.

Comment: Can you please inspect what is the outcome of different part of `self.content.truncate(140)` using pry?

Comment: There is content in the content field.

Answer (score 0):

There was definitely something in the content field, I checked in my console and was able to get a value. I was also able to get a result in my console with sample_question.content.truncate(140)

I also added the pry gem, got the same result, value of nil for Question.first.truncated_content.

I played with uzaif's suggestion to use "map" in my collection select instead of Question.all. It created an array of arrays and :id and :content were not in the mapped array. It produced [["Lo...", 1]]

With https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map I tried hash merge and map with index with no success.

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate 
I copied and pasted the truncate example. The method in my model is now as follows:

```
def truncated_content
  truncate(self.content, length: 70)
end
```

Thanks for the help!